# Using .Offset with a fixed range

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset, autofilter

The script below works without

```
.Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = "TEST"
```

The script takes a list of iPads and Tablets on a spreadsheet and finds the ones that don't have SIM cards.

With the intended results, I need to offset back 2-3 columns and change D & E's result to "TEST" for example.

The code below runs for the G column and to get offset to work means expanding from (A:T). This breaks everything below though and now the script loses focus and doesn't know what to filter.

I know either set range needs changing, or I need to approach offset differently without losing the focus and accidently changing rows that aren't filtered.

```vb
Sub FilterOut()

Dim arr(): Dim arrResult()
Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Long

Set rg = Range("G:G")
arr = Application.Transpose(rg)

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i), "SAMSUNG TABLET") <> 0 Or InStr(arr(i), "IPAD") <> 0 Then
    If InStr(arr(i), "64GB") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "64GB", "!@!")
        If InStr(arr(i), "CELL") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "4G") = 0 And InStr(arr(i), "5G") = 0 Then
            If InStr(arr(i), "!@!") <> 0 Then arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "!@!", "64GB")
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To j)
            arrResult(j) = arr(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

With rg
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, criteria1:=arrResult, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'My issue starts here:
    .Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = "TEST"

End With

End Sub
```

I tried:

`Set rg = Range("A:T")`

`.Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = "TEST"`

> Run time error - Subscript error out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the first parameter of the `Offset` function - the `row` argument is set to 1, when your range `rg` is an entire column and therefore can't be offset up and down. If you replaced your existing `.Offset(1, -4)` with `.Offset(0, -4)` then it will not throw the error, although I'm not sure from your question what you're wanting to happen, whether this would be a satisfactory fix.

EDIT:
Can't believe I didn't notice - if you do the `Resize` operation before the `Offset`, then the range being offset is no longer an entire column and it doesn't throw an error.
So, replace

```
.Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = "TEST"
```

with

```
.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -4).Value = "TEST"
```

Comment: Thank you! A human brain is better than AI's still, clearly. I will be contacting you when GPT starts the Inevitable robot uprising. Seriously though thanks, Its for a work project and you've saved me so much time with such a small change.

Answer (score 0):

`Set rg = Range("G:G")` is over a million rows, the `arr = Application.Transpose(rg)` truncates it to 65,536. Scan the sheet down to the last row of data and update the rows directly, no need to filter.

```vb
Sub FilterOut2()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, s As String
    Dim rg As Range, i As Long, n As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet ' or wb.Sheets("SheetName")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            s = Replace(.Cells(i, "G"), "64GB", "")
            If (InStr(s, "SAMSUNG TABLET") > 0 _
             Or InStr(s, "IPAD") > 0) Then
             
                If InStr(s, "CELL") = 0 _
                   And InStr(s, "4G") = 0 _
                   And InStr(s, "5G") = 0 Then
                     .Cells(i, "C").Resize(, 2) = "TEST" ' C:D
                     n = n + 1
                End If
                
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows updated", vbInformation

End Sub
```